# Mapping ⌘→ to ^Q→ in iTerm2 doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, iterm, tmux

I'm trying to make iTerm2 and tmux play nicer with eachother (without using the builtin tmux functions; I'd like my windows and panes managed by myself).

Therefore, I want to map <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to a key sequence starting with <kbd>^Q</kbd> (my tmux prefix), followed by <kbd>→</kbd>.

<kbd>^Q</kbd> is `0x11`, and <kbd>→</kbd> is `^[[C`, i.e. `0x1b 0x5b 0x43`. However, if I try to make this mapping in the iTerm Preferences (Keys→Key Mappings, with the "Send Hex Codes" setting), it doesn't work, i.e. it doesn't switch my panes as I would expect.

[image: Key mapping that doesn't work]

If, shortly after pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> I press <kbd>→</kbd> again, the active pane to the right is selected, so the ^Q must be coming through. If I just map it to `0x1b 0x5b 0x43` (<kbd>→</kbd>), it works, too.

Is this a limitation of iTerm2 itself; can I not send longer key sequences? Is it sending the keys too fast for tmux?

I also tried using the "Send with vim special keys" setting, but it doesn't seem to work at all; if I enter "<C-Q><Right>" it sends that text literally.

*iTerm2 Build 3.0.8 on macOS Sierra.*

Answer (score 1):

I found [this on iTerm2's FAQ](https://www.iterm2.com/faq.html) page. I'm not sure if it answers your question. Let us know.

[image]

Comment: Sadly it doesn't. `$TERM`, and the terminal type setting are both `xterm-256color`. My arrow keys are working fine, as I wrote I can even map a key combination to send an arrow key escape sequence, just not Control-Q _and_ and arrow key escape sequence. I have cursor application mode turned off.